# mod-mono-server4 and FileNotFoundException

Tags: linux, apache, mono, monodevelop

I have been trying to get Mono and the apache module running without success.  when I try to run mod-mono-server4 from the command line i get a FileNotFoundException:

The actual error is:

```
slackKingServer:/# mod-mono-server4
Handling exception type FileNotFoundException
Message is Could not load file or assembly 'mod-mono-server4, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
IsTerminating is set to True
Could not load file or assembly 'mod-mono-server4, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean v_quiet) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server:RealMain (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'mod-mono-server4, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'mod-mono-server4, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean v_quiet) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server:RealMain (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I know it is saying it can't load mod-mono-server4, but I am not sure where it is looking at for the file.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is getting the above error.  I fixed by doing the following.  Now keep in mind I built everything from source in a Slackware 14.1 environment.

I had to copy the content of the xsp gac directory to the mono gac directory.

I ran diff -r /xsp/gac /mono/gac

then copied the files that were missing ton the mono GAC directory